# How to draw two galaxies at manually set locations on GalSim

Tags: galsim

I want to draw a circular galaxy to the left and another circular galaxy to the right. All the GalSim demos seem to draw galaxies at randomly set locations -- how would I create 2 gal variables that have the respective position information, and place it within a larger image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

GalSim demo5, demo7, and demo10 do what you want: they draw galaxies to fixed, pre-specified locations within a larger image.  Demos 5 and 10 have galaxies on a grid, while demo7 has just two galaxy images drawn into a single larger image (which I believe is exactly what you want to do).  To summarize briefly, you create a galsim.Bounds() object that specifies the region in the larger image into which you want to draw each object, then draw into a sub-image that has that bounds.  But the example scripts I mentioned show this in detail with many comments, so I encourage you to look at those.